# Default constructor of primitive types in assignment to anonymous instance

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void f(T& t)
{
    t = T();
}

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    f(x);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Does the C++11 standard define what the output shall be?  My compiler outputs 0, however I was under the impression the default constructor of a primitive type is a null operation or undefined behaviour.

Comment: Primitive types don't have a default constructor. `int i; i = int();` will result in `i` being 0.

Comment: By default constructor I mean the constructor that takes no parameters.  What function is `int()` calling? (What is the name of this function in the standard?)

Comment: It is called *value initialization*.

Comment: It's functional cast notation. No "null operation" or "undefined behaviour" required.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no "default constructor" involved in your code. Only class types can have constructors. Scalar types have no constructors, default or otherwise.

The `T()` syntax creates a temporary object initialized by so called *value-initialization*. Value-initialization resolves to constructor call only for *class* types, and only for those with *user-defined* constructors (with some nuances in C++11). For other types value-initialization does not involve any constructors at all. It proceeds in accordance with its own specific and rather elaborate initialization rules that define the initial value of the data directly, without involving any constructors (see 8.5 in the language specification).

For scalar types value-initialization performs zero-initialization. This is why your code is guaranteed to output zero. The exact specifics of the abstract initialization process changed between the versions of C++ language standard, however since the beginning of times C++ language guaranteed that `T()` expression for `T == int` evaluated to zero. I.e. even in C++98 your code will output zero.

It is a common misconception that all these `T(...)` expressions somehow necessarily imply constructor calls. In reality, `T(...)` expression is a functional cast expression (regardless of the number of arguments) (see 5.2.3 in the language specification), which might resolve to constructor call in some narrow set of specific situations and has nothing to do with any constructors in other situations.

For example, this code

```
struct S { int x, y; };

S s = S();
```

is guaranteed to initialize `s` with zeros (both `s.x` and `s.y`) despite that fact that class `S` has a default constructor. I brought up this example specifically to illustrate the fact that even in situations when the default constructor exists, the `T()` expression can still completely ignore it and work by its own rules instead.

Comment: So in your last example would `S s2;` also initialize `s2.x` and `s2.y` to zero?

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos - Fathomling: No, it would not. Why would it? `S s2;` does not perform value-initialization, so `s2` will contain garbage. Note that in C++03 the constructor is not called in this case, even though it exists (in such cases constructors are called only for non-POD classes). In C++11 the constructor is conceptually called, but since it does nothing, the object remains uninitialized. I.e. the final result is the same (garbage in `s2`), but the conceptual behavior is different between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: It seems somehow inconsistent. I've always thought of `T()` and `T t;` as the same thing except the later is named - but it seems to be way more complicated that this.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos - Fathomling: No, since the beginning of standardized times (C++98) the `()` was a special form of an initializer. Using `()` initializer vs. not using any initializer at all - these are two completely different situations with completely different initialization behaviors. The exact meaning (physical and conceptual) of `()` initializer changed from C++98 to C++03 and from C++03 to C++11, but its functionality in basic cases has always been the same. For basic types, `()` always forces zero-initialization, while absence of any initializer leaves the garbage values untouched.

Comment: The apparent inconsistency stems from the fact that type system of C++ language is inconsistent. It has class types and non-class types. It has POD types and non-POD types. It has aggregate types and non-aggregate types. It has classes with user-declared and compiler-declared constructors. And so forth. This classification greatly affects the behavior of the types in many contexts, including initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what the standard says regarding your question:

In *8.5. paragraph 10:*

An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

---

In *8.5. paragraph 7:*

To value-initialize an object of type T means:

- if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
  default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
  constructor);
- if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
  is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
  called.
- if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
- **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

---

emphasis mine. So, since `int` isn't even a class type, it falls under the last rule, and gets zero-initialized, so it's an absolutely correct behavior.

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct. The point is, that `int` is not a **class type** and hence zero-initialization applies. This has nothing to do with the existence or non-existence of a user-provided constructor.

Comment: @MWid, there's also "otherwise, the object is zero-initialized" part.

Comment: Of course you're right, but your emphasis is a bit misleading. `int` is zero-initialized because of the 4th rule and not the 2nd, because it is no class type at all.

Comment: @Christian, yes, I've chosen some bad phrasing indeed, I'll edit it.

Comment: Thi first part of your answer is misleading. What actually happens is this: If `T` is a _simple-type-specifier_ (e.g. `int`) then the expression `T()` creates a prvalue of type `T`, which is value-initialized. (see 5.2.3 Explicit type conversion). 8.5 10 has nothing to do with this question.